# How to add user info to Sentry context?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sentry

I try to add user info to Sentry context, but it never works. The event details show empty user.

```
Sentry.getContext().user = UserBuilder().setEmail("tester@email.com").build()
Sentry.capture(EventBuilder().withMessage("Test message.").build())
```

Any ideas what I do wrong?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I updated, the question. The dashboard shows only the event with no user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note:

Sentry has released a [new Android SDK](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/android/). It's still a beta release though.
Also, [came out today a blog post](https://blog.sentry.io/2019/12/10/new-android-sdk-how-to/) about migrating from `sentry-android` 1.7 to 2.0.

With regards to your snippet:

You're building the event before passing it to `Sentry.capture`:

```
Sentry.getContext().user = new UserBuilder().setEmail("tester@email.com").build();
Sentry.capture(EventBuilder().withMessage("Test message."));
```

Use the overload that takes the builder, so the SDK can read the Context data and add it to the event.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for the answer. I have just migrated to the new SDK and what's the proper way of capturing custom events with the user context?

Comment: I'd suggest raising a question here so people could try answering.